# Cakephp 3.0 ROOT variable gets set wrong

Tags: cakephp-3.0

After a stock install and creation of a basic controller, the environment variables are being set wrong.

For example, ROOT gets set as follows:

/var/www/html/appname/src//var/www/html/appname

In other words, the Apache webserver DocumentRoot is being appended to it.

Why?

Comment: Figure out where it's being defined and check what's going on... by default the `ROOT` _constant_ is defined as `dirname(__DIR__)` in `src/config/paths.php` (if you're really talking about environment variables, then you need to come up with some details regarding that, as no such thing is defined by CakePHP or the App template by default).

Comment: It is just set to the default:

    define('ROOT', dirname(\_\_DIR\_\_);

Comment: The problem might be solved..

Comment: If so, please add the solution as an answer, or close/delete the question if it's not helpful for future readers (like a typo for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I learned is that if I specify the absolute path to the file in a controller, the Apache DocumentRoot gets appended to the ROOT variable. For example:

```
public function getFile() {
    // disable the default layout for the view
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout(false);
    $path = ROOT . '/file/file.txt';
    $this->response->file($path, array('download' => true));
    return $this->response;
}
```

The browser cannot find the file at location /var/www/html/app/src//var/www/html/app/src/file/file.txt

However the following works as expected:

```
public function getFile() {
    // disable the default layout for the view
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout(false);
    $path = '/file/file.txt';
    $this->response->file($path, array('download' => true));
    return $this->response;
}
```

The ROOT location seems to get automatically pre-prended to the path I have set above. I was not aware of this and haven't read anything about it in the documentation, so I am still not sure why it works this way.